# Tensorflow custom Object Detector: model_main_tf2 doesn't start training

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

**Problem summary**: The tensorflow custom object detector never starts fine-tuning when i follow the guide in docs. It doesn't throw an exception either.

**What i've done:** I have installed the object detector api and run a succesful test as according to the [docs](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

I then followed the guide about training a custom object detector algorithm [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#), including modifying the pipeline.config file. As per the guide i run

```
model_main_tf2.py  --model_dir=<path1> --pipeline_config_path=<path2> --alsologtostderr
```

where path1 and path2 are paths like

```
 D:/COCO/models/workspace/duck-demo/pre-trained-models/efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32/pipeline.config
```

The output is shown below. The output, including its many warnings, is expected output as per the guide. However, it was expected to start training afterwards. Instead it just returns, without error nor training. What seems to be the problem here?

**output:**

```
...
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.gamma
W0326 09:24:46.180965 16300 util.py:160] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.beta
W0326 09:24:46.180965 16300 util.py:160] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.beta
...
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. 
Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W0326 09:24:46.181965 16300 util.py:168] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. 
Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
```

Comment: Do any of the solutions discussed in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8892) page solve the problem?

Comment: Just read through and tried some of the solutions. CHanging number of steps doesn't change output. Changing "fine_tune_check_point_type" from "classification" to "detection" gives me an error trying to rename a checkpoint file. Not sure what it means.

Comment: Did you test the tensorflow installation with `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py`?

Comment: I did yes. I tried some more with the solutions posted in your link and it worked! Especially changing "fine_tune_check_point_type" from "classification" to "detection" and reset the directory to its initial status worked for me.

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer, or i can do so myself.

Comment: Glad to know. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8892) with many possible solutions being discussed for different types of TensorFlow 2 models for your problem. There's a good chance one of them would help.

Just as a rule of thumb, it's a good idea to always test your installation by running the command `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py` before actually proceeding to train anything to diagnose any possible issues early

Comment: Thanks. As i wrote though, i already did succesful test before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, just posting here because after many agonizing hours I finally resolved it, so I wanted to post my fix in case it helps somewhere else.

After spending too much time thinking the issue was with my model variables, I went back and went over every step in the TF object detection api installation to make sure nothing was wrong.  I then found that my Windows 10 environmental variables was pointed at the CUDA 11.2 version but I had 11.3 installed, I changed the path and it worked perfectly.  I would recommend anyone who isn't getting an error message to check they installed the environment correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait, it can take a while and this is something the developers [warned about](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#training-the-model):

> The output will normally look like it has “frozen”, but DO NOT rush to cancel the process. The training outputs logs only every 100 steps by default, therefore if you wait for a while, you should see a log for the loss at step 100.

> The time you should wait can vary greatly, depending on whether you are using a GPU and the chosen value for batch_size in the config file, so be patient.

If it's not crashing, it seems like it's working. There's a logging parameter you can change in `model_main_tf2.py` somewhere. You can decrease from 100 to like 5 or 10 if you want to see verbose more frequently.

Comment: I saw that yes, but I don't think this is it. Just to be clear: The method returns ! So i can enter new input in cmd.